# AngularJS Accordion is-open call to function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to dinamically open a element of the accordion if it's the current element of my task list. This is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="taskController">
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
            <uib-accordion-group heading="{{task.id}}: {{task.subject}}"  ng-repeat="task in datafromRedmine.issues" class="priority{{task.priority.id}}">
                <div id="midRow">

                    {{task.tracker.name}}-{{task.project.name}}

                </div>
(...)
</uib-accordion-group>

    </uib-accordion>
</div>
```

Who uses an Angular Controller with this function:

```
$scope.isTheCurrent = function (id){
        return(id == $scope.Currentid);
}
```

I'm trying to add next to ng-repeat a is-open="{{isTheCurrent(task.id)}}", but console says

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{isTheCurrent(task.id)}}] starting at [{isTheCurrent(task.id)}}].
```

How can I return a boolean checking if the task.id from the ng-repeat is the same as the one I've saved on $scope.currentId?

Comment: Apologies on my previous answer, I overlooked a couple things. The first issue is that the `{{ .. }}` syntax is not required. However that's irrelevant as `is-open` expects an assignable value which means you may have to work out which accordion is active in the controller and pass it as a variable

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-repeat` directive implements some special properties. One of them is `$index`. You can use that in your function call. For instance:

```
<div ng-show="isTheCurrent(datafromRedmine.issues[$index].id)">
     This is current the issue<br>
     {{task}}
</div>
```

For more information on the `$index` special property, read the [AngularJS ng-repeat API Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)